# Encrypting JSON in Google Gears Workerpool

Tags: javascript, json, encryption, gears

I need to encrypt JSON (stringified) data in a Google Gears Workerpool. So far, any implementation I tried either makes the Gears Workerpool bug out, or gives me unwanted encrypted strings.

For example: DES encryption (can't post URL due to account restrictions)

This works brilliantly for most applications, except after encrypting my JSON, it adds linebreaks where I don't want them. Decrypting only results in a broken string that can't be worked with.

For example: AES encryption (can't post URL due to account restrictions)

This also works, in theory, but once I paste the source code into my Workerpool javascript file, the Gears Workerpool gives a vague error message. Upon removing the script from said Workerpool, it all works again.

What I am looking for:

A very simple encryption implementation in javascript, that uses a key to encrypt and decrypt data. Using a key (or password, if you will) is important. Additionally, encrypting a typical JSON string and decrypting that same string should result in perfect results.

It is all pretty important, as it involves medical data for offline usage. So if you have any other ideas on how to safely store JSON data in the Google Gears (sqlite) database, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not answer directly to your question but Dojo offline have something like ENCRYPT and DECRYPT in Dojo SQL syntax this can be helpful. Usage of this can be found [here](http://docs.google.com/View?docid=dhkhksk4_8gdp9gr)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer through a friendly colleague. First I apply the DES encryption, after which I apply BASE64 encoding. This string is then saved into the database.

Decrypting in reverse also works, but leads to another troubling issue. Apparently 2 out of 3 times my JSON is suddenly invalid, upon trying to parse it using javascript's EVAL function (or JSON's JSON.parse method) it returns an exception: Illegal character.

I'll try to fix that or otherwise open up a new question ;)

Cheers!